# Printing the line number of the first occurence of a pattern starting from a specific line number in a file

Tags: bash

How can one print the line number of the first occurence of the string `foo` in a file `abc.text`? I want the line of the first occurence as if `abc.text` started from it's 10th line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use GNU sed this way:

```
sed -n '10,$ {/foo/{=; q}}' abc.text
```

That is:

- In the range from line 10 to the end
- -> For a line matching `foo`
- -> Print the line number and then stop processing

Some tests to demonstrate the correctness:

```
{ for i in {1..9}; do echo $i; done; echo foo; echo bar; echo foo; } | \
sed -n '10,$ {/foo/{=; q}}'
# correctly prints 10

{ for i in {1..9}; do echo $i; done; echo x; echo foo; echo bar; echo foo; } | \
sed -n '10,$ {/foo/{=; q}}'
# correctly prints 11

{ for i in {1..9}; do echo $i; done; } | \
sed -n '10,$ {/foo/{=; q}}'
# correctly prints nothing
```

Comment: `seq` is not portable and not recommended

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
awk 'NR>=10 && $0~/foo/ {print NR; exit}' abc.text
```

Explanations:

- `NR` is the line number, only lines with number `>=10` will be considered
- if you want the output line number to ignore the first 9 lines, `print NR-9`
- `$0~/foo/` is standard pattern matching in `awk`
- the `exit` will stop processing at the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

This may be more readable for some users:

`tail -n +10 abc.txt | grep -n foo | head -1 | cut -f1 '-d:'`

Comment: You'd have to add 9 to the answer.

Comment: I didn't think of that.  I guess it depends how you read the question.